# How does one typeset a pretty, squiggly arrow in xymatrix

Tags: arrows, xy-pic, technical-drawing

I am LaTeX-ing some diagrams in rewriting theory where the rules are modulo a set of equations.  Canonically, a `~`-like symbol is used to denote equivalence.  I have been using `\ar@{~}`.  Here is an example

```
$\xymatrix@C=10pt{
 & & \cdot \ar[drr]^{*} \ar[dll]_{*} & & \\
 \cdot \ar@{.>}[dr]_{*} & & & & \cdot \ar@{.>}[dl]^{*}\\
 & \cdot \ar@{~}[rr] & & \cdot &
}$
```

[image]

If the above is compiled it looks, well, aesthetically unpleasing.  I can't exactly put my finger on it, but it looks crooked.  I think it has to do with the fact that the curved line begins and ends at different heights.  Does anyone have a recommendation for how to get around such issues.

Comment: What about changing the distance between cols? Change the `10pt`

Answer (score 3):

You can make some fine adjustment the length of an "arrow" (here a squiggly line) by following the hop, here `[rr]`, by an expression of the form `-<7pt,0pt>{X}`, which would extend the line to the center of the target node *minus* the given vector, and place the symbol `{X}` there.  In your case you can spcify an empty symbol via `{}`, and the modification below is obtained using `-<3pt,0pt>{}`.  Adjust the parameters to get the appearance you wish.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
$\xymatrix@C=10pt{
 & & \cdot \ar[drr]^{*} \ar[dll]_{*} & & \\
 \cdot \ar@{.>}[dr]_{*} & & & & \cdot \ar@{.>}[dl]^{*}\\
 & \cdot \ar@{~}[rr]-<3pt,0pt>{} & & \cdot &
}$ 
\end{document}
```

Similarly a `\save[]+<vector>{} \ar... \restore` construction will allow you to adjust the starting point.